# Install chromedriver on google Dataflow job

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-cloud-dataflow

I wanted to migrate a scraping containerised python application to an apache beam pipeline that I can run on dataflow. My scraping application uses 2 scraping methods: a curl response and selenium chromedriver.

While running the application locally, everything works fine as the scraping is successfully running using both methods because I have chromedriver installed on my local machine.

The issue now is on dataflow. I know that google dataflow is serverless. I'm just wondering if there is a way I can install chromedriver in the dataflow workers while running my pipeline?

When I deploy my pipeline without the driver, the error looks like this:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home [while running 'ParDo(ScrapeContent)-ptransform-47']`

Comment: I guess you'd have to use a custom container image to run your Dataflow job: more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers)

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, checkout the answer

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to use [custom containers in Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#python_1)

You configure a docker container where you install apache-beam[GCP] and chromedriver and all your requirements

After that you build your image: `gcloud builds submit . --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT/$REPO:$TAG`

And when you want to submit your job to dataflow:

```
 python main.py 
--project=project 
--region=region
--temp_location=location 
--runner=DataflowRunner 
--experiments=use_runner_v2 
--sdk_container_image=image_path
```